# Default values for user defined objects in Java 8

Tags: java, type-inference

So i'm a little confused here idk if i'm just missing something really obvious but hopefully this is a simple question

I created a user defined object with two constructors the default no arg constructor and a constructor that takes in an integer as an argument

I then created a reference var in another class without creating the object
so something like this

```
public class A{
     int num;

     public A{}
     public A(int num){this.num = num;}
}

public class B{
  A a;
}
```

So this is where my question comes in , in class B the instance variable **a** by my understanding should get a default value of **null** since it's an object reference but instead i'm getting a default value of **0**

from looking at my code I know this behavior is being caused by the param type of the int param in my class A constructor

```
public A(int num){this.num = num;}
```

Why is this happening ? why is it not null ?

Thanks

Comment: "in class B the instance variable a by my understanding should get a default value of null since it's an object reference but instead i'm getting a default value of 0" - no, you're not. It's null. It's `num` that has the value of 0.

Comment: As the object can't be 0.

Comment: Primitives are initialized to 0 by default, except for boolean which is false.  Object references are initialzed to null.  That's all the initialization Java does for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you say

```
B b = new B();
// b.a == null #TRUE
b.a = new A();
// b.a == null # FALSE
// b.a.num == 0 #TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A{
    int num;
   public A(){
    }
  public A(int num){this.num = num;}
}

public class B {
 A a;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       B b = new B();
      System.out.println(b.a.num);//Will Throw Null pointer exception if you 
      try to access a,in any case it will not be 0
   }
}
```